# Android HTTP set proxy

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have some code that I am trying to get to work with Android API 21. It was written with a version of HTTP Client 3.x and Android uses a version of HTTP Client that is definitely 4.x but not 4.5. So I am wondering how to update this section of code specifically

```
if(getProxy() != null) {
    client.getHostConfiguration().setProxy(getProxy().getHost(),getProxy().getPort());
    if (HttpProxyCredentials.isProxySet()) {
        AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope(getProxy().getHost(), getProxy().getPort()); 
        client.getState().setProxyCredentials(authScope, new NTCredentials(HttpProxyCredentials.getUserName(),
                HttpProxyCredentials.getPassword(),
                "",HttpProxyCredentials.getDomain()));
```

Any one know how to do this Android?

Comment: As google is deprecating the HttpClient on API 22 my advice is to use another library or the default java standard HttpUrlConnection to get this work.

Comment: I can't. Simply put there is too much code too reliant on the http classes. Plus this is a library I am modifying for a program that runs in API 21 and it would take far more time and effort to update everything to the newest API.

Comment: What about using this implementation [Apache Http Client Android Port](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html), you can add it as a dependency on your build.gradle like this `dependencies { compile org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1 }`